# Decoding and encoding of byte array while dumping it in a file

Tags: json, python-3.x

Below is the response which i get while scanning a DynamoDb table, sth like this.(shorter version of the data).

```
{'id': {'S': '123'}, 'applicationName': {'S': 'swagger_petstore_1_0_0_mock_app'}, 'endpointIds': {'SS': ['hzl3ns24gzh6egwsltoaa7z4llvc3wq2']}, 'configDetails': {'S': '{"propertyPrefix":"","properties":[],"propertyOverrides":[]}'}, 'description': {'S': 'This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about Swagger at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For this sample, you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.'}, 'fullyQualifiedDockerImageUrl': {'S': 'R2-6-0.unified-managers.internal.tibco.com:5000/icyxmnf4ayukqsnylrs35spraggw3q27/4uv75dk6m6mg52xrezprwvq7w4x23i7t:1550829818352'}, 'lastModifiedBy': {'S': '3xxyd4szt62rop4npspdrihr5ufyjtwq'}, 'desiredInstanceCount': {'N': '1'}, 'appType': {'S': 'api-mock-app'}, 'version': {'S': '1.0'}, 'isSampleApp': {'N': '0'}, 'endpointBeansBytes': {'B': b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xed[\xebo\xdb8\x12\xffW\x08\xef}\xb8\x05\x1c;\xaf\xb6@pw\xb8\xb4i\x0f\xc1v\xdb\xa0i\xee\xf6\x90\x04]F\xa2mn%Q!\xa98n\x90\xff\xfdf\x86\xd4\xc3\xb6$\xcbY\xa7M\x0f\xfd\x92X|\x0eg~\xf3\xe2\xe3\xfc\xae\'\xc3\xdeAo\xf2%|\x19\x03U\x15\xd2\xa1\xc1\x8f\x97N\xb2\xf2\xd2\t\xf8\xfe?\xa8\xb4CVa?\x00\x00'}}
```

in order to write this in the filesystem.

I have done this.

```
with open("backup.json", "w+") as f:
                f.write(json.dumps(response, indent=JSON_INDENT, default=str))
```

Please note that I have used default decoding method(because endpointBeansBytes was not json serializable ).

But when I am loading this data this way(tried couple of ways):

1) `json.load(open(backup.json))`
I am able to read endpointBeansBytes but it is not the same data that we backed up.

2) converted this data using this.

`endpointBeansBytes['B'] = str.encode(endpointBeansBytes['B'])`
and still it is not the same data.

3) `endpointBeansBytes['B'] = endpointBeansBytes['B'].encode('utf-8')`
and still it is not the same data.

My question is,

1) what decoding method is used by default in `json.dump`?

2) in order to encode data from step 1, what needs to be done?

3) can i use some other decoding/encoding instead of default provided by `json.dump` so that authenticity of data should not be lost.

Comment: is your input data correct? I think `{'S': 123}` shouldn't have that trailing `}` bracket.

Comment: Do you really get a *JSON response* (that would be *a string*)? If you get a Python data structure (nested dicts and lists with keys and values), then please don't call it a "JSON response" - those two things are completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JSON has no support for binary data, you must encode the binary into string form. It seems that binary values are denoted by a `'B'` key in your case.

A common approach to convert binary data to string is the base64 encoding.

```
import json, base64, copy

response = {
    'id': {'S': '123'}, 
    'desiredInstanceCount': {'N': '1'},
    'isSampleApp': {'N': '0'},
    'endpointBeansBytes': {'B': b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xed...'}
}

# --- saving ---------------------------------------------------------------
backup = copy.deepcopy(response)

for val in backup.values():
    if list(val)[0] == 'B':
        val['B'] = base64.b64encode(val['B']).decode('ascii')

with open("backup.json", "w+") as f:
    json.dump(backup, f, indent=2)

# --- restoring ------------------------------------------------------------
with open("backup.json", "r") as f:
    restore = json.load(f)

for val in restore.values():
    if list(val)[0] == 'B':
        val['B'] = base64.b64decode(val['B'].encode('ascii'))

print(response)
print(restore)
```

Notes:

- `json.dump()` and `json.load()` write/read directly to/from file objects
- `base64.b64encode()` *still* gives you bytes, but these bytes are all in the ASCII range and are safe to convert to string using `.decode('ascii')`.
- reading is the mirror operation - convert the base64 string to bytes using `.encode('ascii')` and then restore the original bytes via `base64.b64decode()`.
- I'm using `deepcopy` so I don't modify the original data.
- Neither the `default` parameter to `json.dump` nor a custom `JSONEncoder` are a good fit for this task, as the necessary context (*"object with only one key named `'B'`"*) cannot be seen by those. They only see the value itself. They would work for JSON encoding, since it's obvious when an input value is `bytes`, but they would not work for JSON decoding, since it's not obvious which input string is supposed to be base64-decoded, and which input string is supposed to be left alone. In other words, there is no guarantee that every string that *would be* base64-decodable is meant to be decoded.